# How can I use gzip on a string?

Tags: go, gzip

I want to use Go to read out a chunk from a file, treat it as a `string` and `gzip` this chunk. I know how to read from the file and treat it as a `string`, but when it comes to `compress/gzip` I am lost.

Should I create an `io.writer`, which writes to a `buf` (byte slice), use `gzip.NewWriter(io.writer)` to get a `w *gzip.Writer` and then use `w.Write(chunk_of_file)` to write the chunk of file to `buf`? Then I would need to treat the string as a byte slice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use golang's "compress/gzip" package to gzip a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890648/how-can-i-use-golangs-compress-gzip-package-to-gzip-a-file)

Comment: I'm confused by your question, in Go a string *is* a []byte so if you want it to be one, just convert it as such []byte(mystringvar)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can just write using [`gzip.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Writer) as it implements `io.Writer`.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
    if _, err := gz.Write([]byte("YourDataHere")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := gz.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b.Bytes())
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EU3ye4Qoozp)

If you want to set the compression level (Default is -1 from [`compress/flate`](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#pkg-constants)) you can use [`gzip.NewWriterLevel`](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#NewWriterLevel).

Comment: I feel like it should be noted that the Writer will not actually write the compressed bytes to the buffer until `gz.Flush()` is called. The flush is also called with `gz.Close()`, but the playground example never gets that far.

Comment: One more thing is that Flush() only writes the _current_ data to the buffer. It doesn't finish off the whole GZIP format. So, in this case, it's pretty useless, since what's written on the last line is not a valid GZIP structure. You need to call Close() _before_ you do anything with the buffer.

Comment: @PhilKulak Thanks for the correction. I've changed the example code to close the writer before printing the buffer contents.

Comment: You can just call Close().  From the golang documentation:

func (z *Writer) Close() error
Close closes the Writer, _flushing any unwritten data to the underlying io.Writer_, but does not close the underlying io.Writer.

https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Writer.Close

Comment: Excellent tip @PhilKulak. Just to add a bit, using _defer_ to close the compressed Writer can lead to subtle bugs where the buffer is being used before being closed. This can result in unexpected EOF errors when reading the compressed data. Watch out!

Answer (score 0):

If the result is not going back into a file, then you could just use Flate
directly. You save a bit of overhead from Gzip. Another option is Brotli.
Examples:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "compress/flate"
   "github.com/andybalholm/brotli"
)

func compressFlate(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
   var b bytes.Buffer
   w, err := flate.NewWriter(&b, 9)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   w.Write(data)
   w.Close()
   return b.Bytes(), nil
}

func compressBrotli(data []byte) []byte {
   var b bytes.Buffer
   w := brotli.NewWriterLevel(&b, brotli.BestCompression)
   w.Write(data)
   w.Close()
   return b.Bytes()
}
```

Result:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   data := bytes.Repeat([]byte("hello world"), 999_999)
   f, err := compressFlate(data)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b := compressBrotli(data)
   fmt.Println(len(f) == 21379, len(b) == 40)
}
```

- https://godocs.io/compress/flate
- https://godocs.io/github.com/andybalholm/brotli