# How do I mock writing to a gzip file?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I can write a normal gzip file:

```
var b bytes.Buffer
w := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
w.Write([]byte("hello, world\n"))
w.Close()
```

But I cannot figure out how to mock a gzip file so that I can read that mocked file for my tests:

```
afero.WriteFile(mfs, "/path/to/file.gz", []byte("here is file"), 0644)
```

If I try to read this mock gzip file the error I get is:

```
gzip: invalid header
```

Comment: Do you want to write `b` to the file like `afero.WriteFile(mfs, "/path/to/file.gz", b.Bytes(), 0644)`?   I don't understand the question, but that's one way the code in the question can fit together.

Comment: Are you trying to write or read a gzip file? Your question mentions both.

Comment: Need to write to a gzip file so that my function I am testing can read from that mocked file.

Comment: "write a file of gzipped content" https://stackoverflow.com/a/32017845/4466350

Comment: What do you mean by mock? Isn't `b` in your first code snippet a mock?